# Is there a full list of the names & abbreviation of electronic components

Tags: components, surface-mount

I came by a few electronic components that I don't recognize them from their shape nor their letters printed on the PCB. Is there a full list of the names and abbreviation of electronic components?

Some of the letters that I don't know their components' names.

[image]

- Q (SMD with 2 terminals from one side and 1 terminal from the opposite side)
- Q (Not SMD with 3 terminals & has a tower shape, 3/4 circle)
- IC (3 terminals from one side and 1 wide terminal from the opposite side)
- OJ (It's like SMD resistance with a 0 written on top of it)
- X (It might belong to the below component with SC8.000 writing on top of it)
- SC8.000 written on the curved metal rectangular in the picture below.

[image]

Comment: Bottom image: square? Or rectangular?

Comment: @SolarMike Rectangular

Comment: Are you asking for a full list (can't and doesn't exist) or for information on these specific things (much easier)?

Comment: The PWB has *reference designators* that should match the schematic. There is no universal list, although this list is fairly close to what I have used in my career. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_designator

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a full list of the names and abbreviation of electronic components?

That would require a) full knowledge of all possible components and b) full cooperation of all engineers ever. So, no, such a list does not exist.

There's a few standards, but your board markings agree with none that I would be aware of. So, we can only help you "acutely" map the letters *for this very board, not for other boards* to types of devices:

- Q is typically associated with transistors. There's multiple legend about where that hails from. It's probably a thing from vacuum tube times.
- IC is just "integrated circuit". That can refer to anything from a single transistor with a biasing resistor in the same package, to a billion-gates CPU. In your 4-pin case, probably either such a self-biased transistor, a diode pair, or a linear voltage regulator, but it might also be a switch-mode supply, a or some other power electronics.
- OJ is "orange juice". The "O" is probably a zero, and it's probably supposed to mean "0 Ω resistor or jumper", which "explains" the J
- X is for Crystal
- And that's exactly what the silver component is, a crystal oscillator. "SC" stands for "stress cut", and describes in which direction the piezoelectric crystal inside the metal dome has been sliced. 8 probably means "8 MHz", that's a common resonant frequency.

Comment: [Picture of circuit card with an "SC8.000" crystal mounted on it](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32788964559.html).

Comment: @jonk page can't be found

Comment: Hmm. Still works okay for me. It's on Aliexpress. Is that blocked for you? I'll see if I can pick up an image.

Comment: @jonk it's literally aliexpress telling me "Sorry, the page you requested can not be found:("

Comment: @jonk had to literally disable every adblocker to see that page

Comment: Okay. I was initially thinking that maybe your country has laws against what they want to do with the web data. My country, of course, has no laws to speak of.

Comment: Thank you so much for such detailed educational answer, really appreciated :)

Comment: Hello Marcus, regards same question. In the picture you find a red arrow at the right, right below it there's an IC (As written at the back of the PCB). It has the same shape of the transistor and has 3 terminals & have the height. To test it for being shorted using DMM, do I use the same techniques used with transistors? NPN / PNP using diode & resistance tests? Because in all these tests there're values between all 3 terminals, varies from 0.8KOhms upto 5.5KOhms in resistance test, and 0.3v upto 0.8v in diode mode test. Could this be a shorted IC? I tested it without desoldering it. Thanks

Comment: @AshrafAlshahawy you can't test anything on a board. And the markings on the component will tell you more than you could test with a DMM (which really tells you very little about a semiconductor, anyway)

Comment: (you asked about testing things for shorts before, and you already know you can't just diagnose everything with a DMM! And honestly, trying to measure resistance on a semiconductor, and it varying surprising you: **you are missing electronics basics, no amount of playing around with a DMM can replace understanding how circuits work**.)

Comment: So you're saying that all these demo videos on YouTube and on different forums are wrong.

Comment: Take this for example (Out of many) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b0jCUsenNsY

Comment: And for sorry the component in question doesn't have any thing written on it, which is a bad practice from a company as Samsung, to add an obscure components on its boards. Anyhow, thank you for your answer, really appreciated.

Comment: @AshrafAlshahawy I will not even dignify that video with a click, because honestly, most of electronics videos on youtube **are** wrong, or the very least misleading. And the video might even be right – the fact that you, touching a semiconductor device, think it's surprising the resistance you measure isn't something fixed, tells nothing about the video, but about how little of what you're trying to diagnose you understand. How often do you want me to repeat that?

Comment: @AshrafAlshahawy Also, large companies like Samsung don't use obscure small components, on the very contrary, they are **very** conscious about their supply chains. If there's an unmarked component on your board, chances are either it's actually marked, but hard to read, or it's not an original board by a large manufacturer.

Comment: @AshrafAlshahawy in the case of this specific board, that might have been lacquered/treated afterwards for durability, making the marking very hard to read, so not your fault.

Comment: argh I clicked on the video link... yeah, there's about as much wrong as right in that video, the guy is holding a BJT between his warm fingers to measure ... yeah, really not a great source. as proposed earlier: Get a book or a good written tutorial on electronics, not random videos off youtube.

Comment: And, just in case you're curious, using Q for a transistor instead of the obvious T (or maybe TR) has excellent reasons. Before there were transistors there were transformers, and they got dibs on Ts.